# Database not supporting common Latin characters

Tags: php, html, mysql

The table, which is written in **MySQL** doesn't support common Latin characters, like "é", "ã" and so on. So, if I store `João` in the `nome` attribute, it will be stored as `Joã£o`, and when I call this value on php/html, it will return `Jo�o`.

I tried using `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` and `utf8mb4_general_ci`, but none of those fixed the problem.

Comment: You need to specify the `CHARSET` when you connect to the DB.

Comment: thank you so much, used mysqli_set_charset() and it fixed the problem.